# Difficulty with MatrixPlot

Tags: plotting, matrix

I can use matrixplot for plotting basic functions but I am having problems with matrices. If I try to plot `Z={{3 Cos[t], 2Sin[t]}, {-8 Cos[t], 5Sin[t]}}` for `-50<=t<=50` I get a strange narrow box and I am not sure if it's correct at all. I used the following plot commands:

```
MatrixPlot[Table[UnitStep[{3 Cos[t], 2 Sin[t]}] UnitStep[{-8 Cos[t],5 Sin[t]}], {t, -50, 50}], PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

Is this the correct way to matrix plot what I mentioned?

Comment: The dimension of the table result is `{101, 2}` which is the reason for the narrow box. Not clear exactly what you are trying to achieve with `MatrixPlot`.

Comment: I am just trying to plot this 3x3 matrix with MatrixPlot which according to wolfram generates a plot that gives a visual representation of the values of elements in a matrix. (1) But is what I did correct - was this command sufficient to plot what I wanted as mentioned in the beginning of my question?  (2) Is there a better way to visualize Z with the mentioned range?

Comment: What are the elements of the 3x3 matrix? The function `Z` is a pair of ellipses in parametric form. Maybe you want `ParametricPlot[{{3 Cos[t], 2 Sin[t]}, {-8 Cos[t], 5 Sin[t]}}, {t, -50, 50}]`? Note that in WL the arguments to trig functions are specified in radians, so you probably don't want the range to be -50 to 50.

Comment: I will try out what you mentioned. But I specifically want to try with MatrixPlot and maybe with ArrayPlot later. It should be possible right? I stated the matrix in my question and declared it randomly as Z. But it could be A or B or M. In mathematica, we state the elements of a matrix inside curly braces. I also made a mistake, Z is a 2x2 matrix as it can be evidently seen. Not a 3x3 one.

Answer (score 1):

In such cases you can use `Manipulate`

```
Manipulate[ 
  MatrixPlot[{{3 Cos[t], 2 Sin[t]}, {-8 Cos[t], 5 Sin[t]}}, PlotLabel -> t]
, {t, -50, 50}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is more like what I expected to see but got that weird box instead. Can you point out though what's missing/wrong with my command?

Comment: I am not sure why you are using `UnitStep` here. `Table[UnitStep[{3 Cos[t], 2 Sin[t]}] UnitStep[{-8 Cos[t],5 Sin[t]}], {t, -50, 50}]` is not a list of 2x2 matrices. `UnitStep[{3 Cos[t], 2 Sin[t]}] UnitStep[{-8 Cos[t], 5 Sin[t]}]` gives you a 1x2 matrix.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to include the given interval with the matrix inside MatrixPlot. I used some references from wolfram and gave UnitStep a shot but ig it was used incorrectly. How would UnitStep would then be used for a 2x2 matrix - ie if it's possible to do so with the case I've described? .

Comment: MatrixPlot shows the value of mat[i,j] in i,j box. `UnitStep` is a step function. `UnitStep[t] {{a, b}, {c, d}}` is `{{a, b}, {c, d}}` for  t>0 and `{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}` for t<0. I don't thin you need `UnitStep` for your problem. Alternatively you can plot each element as a function of t, but you don't need `UnitStep` there as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

As pointed out by Sumit, use [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html)

```
Manipulate[
 MatrixPlot[{
   {3 Cos[t], 2 Sin[t]}, {-8 Cos[t], 5 Sin[t]}},
  PlotLegends -> Automatic],
 {{t, 1}, -50, 50, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

To use [`UnitStep`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitStep.html)

```
Attributes[UnitStep]

(* {Listable, NumericFunction, Orderless, Protected, ReadProtected} *)
```

Since `UnitStep` is [`Listable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html),

```
UnitStep[{{3 Cos[t], 2 Sin[t]}, {-8 Cos[t], 5 Sin[t]}}]

(* {{UnitStep[3 Cos[t]], UnitStep[2 Sin[t]]}, {UnitStep[-8 Cos[t]], 
  UnitStep[5 Sin[t]]}} *)
```

With `UnitStep` the array elements are either `0` or `1`

```
Manipulate[
 MatrixPlot[
  UnitStep[{{3 Cos[t2], 2 Sin[t2]}, {-8 Cos[t2], 5 Sin[t2]}}],
  PlotLegends -> Automatic],
 {{t2, 1}, -50, 50, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]